# kafka upgrade to .9 with new consumer api

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We are upgrading our kafka implementation to .9 and using new consumer java api to create consumer.I am using below code for consumer and we are using setting topic to consumer as in LINE A and LINE B is the call to our service which process the messages that we receive. Now the problem is we are getting Exception if our message processing takes more then 30 second.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
            props.put("group.id", "test-group");
            props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
            props.put("heartbeat.interval.ms", "1000");
            props.put("receive.buffer.bytes", 10485760);
            props.put("fetch.message.max.bytes", 5242880);
            props.put("enable.auto.commit", false);
    //with partition assigned to consumer


            KafkaConsumer<Object, Object> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
           // TopicPartition partition0 = new TopicPartition("TEST-TOPIC", 0);
            //consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(partition0));
            //assign topic to consumer without partition
//LINE A
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("TEST-TOPIC"), new ConsumerRebalanceListenerImp());
            List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
            while (true) {
                try {
                    ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records = consumer.poll(1000);
                    consumeFromQueue(records);//LINE B
                    consumer.commitSync();

                } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("CommitFailedException");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Exception in while consuming messages");
                }
```

Exception is

> 2016-03-03 10:47:35.095  INFO 6448 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : Marking the coordinator 2147483647 dead.
>   2016-03-03 10:47:35.096 ERROR 6448 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : Error ILLEGAL_GENERATION occurred while committing offsets for group TEST-GROUP
>   CommitFailedException
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:552)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator$OffsetCommitResponseHandler.handle(ConsumerCoordinator.java:493)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:665)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:644)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:133)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:107)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.onComplete(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:380)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:274)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:320)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:213)

Above exception comes while committing offset.
Any suggestions would help thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the new consumer is single-threaded, and the only way that it can keep the heartbeat with the consumer group is by polling or committing the offset, after 30 seconds the group coordinator is marking your consumer as dead and calling for a group rebalance. 
For this situation you can either increase the `request.timeout.ms` or split the work of consuming and processing between 2 threads.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I tried adding "request.timeout.ms" to 70000, it gave me the same exception even though message processing took 30000.

Comment: Not sure why it is not taking any effect. I even tried setting "session.timeout.ms" to 70000 but it gave me exception saying "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ApiException: The session timeout is not within an acceptable range."  I was thinking about your second suggestion, but if some thing goes wrong in processing threads how i would handle it? adding it again to topic as new message and revert the changes caused by message before exception?

Comment: increase the group.max.session.timeout.ms as well

Comment: Tried setting it. Not having any effect logs come like :-                                   2016-03-10 16:43:26.339  WARN 10376 --- [ask-scheduler-4] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : The configuration group.max.session.timeout.ms = 40000 was supplied but isn't a known config.
2016-03-10 16:43:26.341  INFO 10376 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 0.9.0.1
2016-03-10 16:43:26.342  INFO 10376 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : 23c69d62a0cabf06

Comment: I am passing "group.max.session.timeout.ms" it as property like other properties

Comment: you need to set it in the server.properties file, please take a look at http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: @nautilus
"the only way that it can keep the heartbeat with the consumer group is by polling or committing the offset". You are wrong here.
it can keep the heartbeat with the consumer group only by polling.

Comment: @Black_Rider I was under the impression that when you do a commit under the hood it will also call poll hence maintaining the heartbeat.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the number of messages returned by poll() by setting

```
max.partition.fetch.bytes
```

to a some suitable threshold that is larger than your largest message, but so low that you will get less messages per poll.

Kafka 0.10.x has support to explicitly limit the number of messages returned to the client by setting

```
max.poll.records
```